# Scraping tables and writing rows to CSV

Tags: python, performance

I'm working on a project that scrapes about 400,000 records in tables of 20 records each. Currently my script creates a complete list of URLs for the pages, and then for each URL it opens the page, finds the table with BeautifulSoup, and scrapes each row. As it scrapes each row it writes the row to a CSV:

```
def scrape_table(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    table = soup.find('table' , {'id' : 'BigTable'})
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cells) > 0:
            name_bits = cells[0].get_text().strip().split(',')
            first_name = name_bits[0].strip()
            last_name = name_bits[1].strip()
            species = cells[1].get_text().strip()
            bunch = re.sub(u'[\xa0\xc2\s]+',' ',str(cells[5]),flags=re.UNICODE).strip()
            bunch_strings = list(BeautifulSoup(bunch).td.strings)
            weight = bunch_strings[1].strip()
            bunch_match = re.match("dob:(.*) Mother: \$(.*)",bunch_strings[2].strip())
            dob = date_format(bunch_match.groups()[0].strip())
            mother = bunch_match.groups()[1].strip()            
            row_of_data = {
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name' : last_name,
                'species'   : species,
                'weight'    : weight,
                'dob'       : dob,
                'mother'    : mother
            }
            data_order = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'mother', 'weight', 'kesavan']
                csv_row(row_of_data,data_order,'elephants')
        else:
            continue

def csv_row(data,fieldorder,filename, base=__base__):
    full_path = __base__+filename+'.csv'    
    print "writing", full_path
    with open(full_path, 'a+') as csvfile:
        linewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldorder, delimiter='|',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        linewriter.writerow(data)
```

I'm wondering if this would be more efficient if I wrote each page of results to the CSV at once instead of writing each row. Or would that use more RAM and slow down the rest of my computer? Other ways to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(full_path, 'a+') as csvfile:
    linewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldorder, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    linewriter.writerow(data)
```

is a performance killer. It has to construct the filename, open the file, construct an object, write data to disk and close the file again *for every single line*. That means it has to do at least three system calls and wait for the disk driver/controller to signal "file closed and flushed succesfully".

What you should try is to at least keep the file open during the entire process. The memory cost of that is negligible. So,

```
def scrape_table(url, linewriter):
    # do scraping to get data
    linewriter.writerow(data)
```

And call that with

```
with open(full_path, 'a+') as csvfile:
    linewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldorder, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for url in a_bunch_of_urls:
        scrape_table(url, linewriter)
```

Usually, using more RAM does not slow down anything. Caching results in RAM instead of recomputing them is probably *the* most common optimization technique.

Comment: The file may not need to be opened in append mode either if it's left open.

Comment: @martineau Good point. Though I've been running it over chunks of the alphabet, so I do need it to append.